# overlay the screen and highlight a div

Tags: jquery, overlay

As per screenshot below.

This is my pic.

[image]

I wan like overlay points like this.

[image]

This my html

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs">
 <div class="media point top-common">
 <div class="media-left">
      <img data-holder-rendered="true" src="/assets/img/dashboard/icn-point.png" class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="64x64">
 </div>
 <div class="media-body">
      <h1 class="media-heading">744</h1>
      <div class="point-label">Points</div>
 </div>
 <div class="view-more" style="background-color:transparent;">
 <div class="row">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: provide some html to reproduce the problem!! Your question is unclear as of now!!

Comment: increase the z-index of the points div.